# What's one of the best increase techniques that can avoid or minimize eyelets for sweaters?

Tags: knitting, technique-selection

For my sweater knitting technique, I use M1R (Make 1 Right) and M1L (Make 1 Left) with two knit stitches in between every other round as shown in RJ Knits video on his top-down sweater ([here](https://youtu.be/GV05jGAuGIk?t=380)) and it leaves some small eyelets and it made me wonder if there is a better increase that would improve it specifically for this increase pattern.

**Disclaimer**: I have no affiliation whatsoever with the website link(s) posted.

Comment: The video is more than half an hour long. Can you include a timestamp where the increase is shown?

Comment: @Elmy Done! The reason I didn't put it in originally is that I assumed that anyone with enough experience to answer would already know what I was talking about but I realize how stupid that is now, thanks.

Comment: That's not stupid, and, besides, "anyone with enough experience to answer [*will*] already know what [you are] talking about". The problem is that they might be hard to find :)

Comment: @Joachim Whoops, little grammatical error, I meant that it was stupid to not include a timestamp, which would help any and all persons with enough knitting experience both see the technique used and be able to know where to look to see what I'm talking about with the eyelets and I agree that it'll be hard to find someone with enough experience, I just hope that I do find them.

Answer (score 2):

The TECHknitter offers a "very nearly invisible increase" that may work for you depending on the kind of stitching you're doing the increases into. What she does is lift the next stitch's parent stitch up onto the left needle untwisted and then she knits into it and into the next stitch. See it [here](https://techknitting.blogspot.com/2007/05/very-nearly-invisible-increase.html).